# Java Merge Sort not giving a favorable outcome

Tags: java, recursion, mergesort

I am a Beginner in java. This is my code for merge sort but it is not giving me favorable results. Could someone please explain the mistake that I have made?

```
public class Test {

public int arr[] = {5,7,8,4,3,2,6,1};

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Test t = new Test();
    System.out.println("Before sorting"+ Arrays.toString(t.arr));
    t.mergeSort(t.arr);
    System.out.println("After Sorting"+ Arrays.toString(t.arr));

}


public void mergeSort(int[] a){
    int n = a.length;
    if(n < 2)
        return;
    int m = n/2;
    int[] left = new int[m];
    int[] right = new int[n - m];
    for(int i = 0;i < m;i++) {
        left[i] = a[i];
    }
    for(int i = m;i < n;i++) {
        right[i - m] = a[i];
    }
    mergeSort(left);
    mergeSort(right);
    merge(left,right,arr);
}

private void merge(int[] left, int[] right, int[] arr2) {
    int n = left.length;
    int m = right.length;
    int i=0,j=0, k=0;
    while(i < n && j < m) {
        if(left[i] < right[j]) {
            arr2[k] = left[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }
        else {
            arr2[k] = right[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }

    }
    while(i<n) {
        arr2[k] = left[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }
    while(j<m) {
        arr2[k] = right[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }


}
}
```

I am not getting a sorted array after implementing the above program. Looks like its not returning the merged array. I am unable to find out the problem and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @JoeC Thank you for the link. I have already debug my code. it looks like when we return after sorting the sub arrays after using the merge method, it is performing the mergesort method on unsorted array.
Ideally it should be merging {5,7} and {4,8} on the left part of my array, but it merges {5,7} and {8,4}, even though i have sorted the {8,4} subarray.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that after mergeSort(left) and mergeSort(right), left and right are not actually sorted, because the array arr is the only thing that actually is modified in the merge-step.

Typically you would implement MergeSort using only a single array and passing the relevant start and end indices for the part of the array you work on in every merge or recursive step.

Then you would have something like mergeSort(int[] a, int leftIndex, int rightIndex) and mergeSort(a, 0, a.length-1) would sort the complete array a.